# How to display file attributes with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networking, network-programming

I need a client/server code, In which the client will choose the file to send to the server and the server should display only the file characteristics on the screen. In which, file characteristics represent actual file size and the number of the characters in the file. I do know how to get file attributes but I wonder how to display only the actual size and the number of the characteristics.

Comment: Try new FileInfo(filePath);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intention is to find the file size, you can use `FileInfo.Length` Property

```
FileInfo info = new FileInfo(PATH);
Console.WriteLine(info.Length); // <== Size in Bytes / Number of characters
```

Note that `1 byte` is same as `1 character` so you get both size and number of characters here.